# Android sqlite union tables, find row belonged to which table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, union

I am kind of new to databases and working with sqlite database, I take union of four tables and the table I get after union, for each row I want to find out which table it belonged to originally. Is there a naive way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
SELECT 'person' AS tablename, * FROM person UNION SELECT 'customer' AS tablename, * FROM customer
```

Comment: sorry but I couldnot understand your suggestion.

Comment: Is there any other way possible?

Comment: Adding a field with the name of your table to your selected fields is the way to go. If you don't understand the suggestion, add what you have to to question, then you can get an answer that is more specific to your problem.